# MVC 2 multilanguage in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, url, controller, multilingual

I'm building a multilanguage application with MVC 2. I read a lot of posts about different ways to get the user's language. I think the best way to save the language, is to put it into the URL like this: www.example.de/language/controller/view.

My questions:
1. how should global.asax.cs look? I tried it to setting something below but it did not work:

```
 routes.MapRoute("Default with language", "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional,
        }, new { lang = "de|en" });
        routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional,
            lang = "en",
        });
```

There was a "en" for example in the route, but it always did not take the Resourse.en, it only took the default.

1. Question: How to get the current language in the controller?
2. Question: How to change the language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help?

[MVC Localization route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712167/asp-net-mvc-localization-route)

Comment: Thank you very much! But now I have an other problem: