# localization of mvc routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Can anyone recommend a library for MVC that manages localization of routes?

For example, as url http://www.mywebsite.com/controller-english/action-english and http://www.mywebsite.com/controller-french/controller-french should both route to the same controller action. If its the french url, culture is setup like so and same for the english version.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712167/asp-net-mvc-localization-route

Answer (score 1):

I've never localized routes before, but this NuGet project might help: [AttributeRouting](http://nuget.org/packages/AttributeRouting). I think you can just use the normal routing for one language then add route attributes for other languages. You will probably have to hard code the languages you support, but it should work.