# ASP.NET MVC Areas localization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, routes, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have an ASP.NET 3 MVC site with areas. The structure is like this:

- Areas

  - Products

    - Views
    - Advanced Search
    - Detail
  - Great Products

    - Views

      - Advanced Search
      - Detail

Currently I can access this:

```
www.domain.com/Products/AdvancedSearch

www.domain.com/GreatProducts/Detail
```

Now we need to internationalise the routing. I want to achieve this:

[English]

```
www.domain.com/Products/AdvancedSearch

www.domain.com/GreatProducts/Detail
```

[Portuguese]

```
www.domain.com/Produtos/PesquisaAvancada

www.domain.com/GrandesProdutos/Detalhe
```

I was able to follow this great [article](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/26/Translating-routes-%28ASPNET-MVC-and-Webforms%29.aspx):

but currently does not support areas.

Can areas support localization? Can you give me some hint to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to dig into the routing and use localization at that label to get the desired functionality.

See [ASP.NET MVC - Localization route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712167/asp-net-mvc-localization-route)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you create a new controller for each language. We can do that like

```
[English]

www.domain.com/en/Products/AdvancedSearch

www.domain.com/en/GreatProducts/Detail


[Portuguese]

www.domain.com/por/Produtos/PesquisaAvancada

www.domain.com/por/GrandesProdutos/Detalhe
```

So I think we can be easier to modify the View Engine to localisation.