# Multilanguage support in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, routes, multilingual

I have a site with multi-language features. I'm still using cookie to detect the language so for example if user choose "English", then I will change the cookie value to "EN" and serve "english page" to user.

I want to change this behavior and read the language from URL instead of cookie. So for example if the current url for product page is

```
www.ezstore.com/product/asus-gtx970
```

I want to change the url to

```
www.ezstore.com/en/product/asus-gtx970 for english
www.ezstore.com/fr/product/asus-gtx970 for french
```

I was thinking of changing the `RouteConfig` and read the URL to get the language value. Is this possible?

My current `RouteConfig` is :

```
routes.MapRoute("Product", "Product/{id}", new {
    controller = "Product",
    action = "Index",
    id = UrlParameter.Optional
});

routes.MapRoute(name: "Default", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new {
    controller = "Home",
    action = "Index",
    id = UrlParameter.Optional
});
```

Comment: I would consider using the HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE header sent by the browser. That's  the language the user prefers.

Comment: Look at [this](http://www.wiliam.com.au/wiliam-blog/web-design-sydney-using-mvc-routing-for-seo-friendly-urls-on-multilingual-sites) article.

Comment: I think this is the answer you need [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712167/asp-net-mvc-localization-route#answer-1712320](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712167/asp-net-mvc-localization-route#answer-1712320)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 5 culture in route and url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764989/asp-net-mvc-5-culture-in-route-and-url)

Answer (score 1):

You can change your custom route as shown :-

```
routes.MapRoute("Product", "{langcode}/Product/{id}", new {
    controller = "Product",
    action = "Index",
    id = UrlParameter.Optional
});
```

Here `langcode` will be a route parameter for language.

and then get the `langcode` route parameter on controller action as shown:-

```
public ActionResult Index(string langcode)
{....}
```

Comment: I actually have alot `MapRoute` in my `RouteConfig`, does that mean I need to add `{langcode}` in every `MapRoute`? Or is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: @warheat1990...Yes..on which ever pages you want `langcode` in the url you have to change their routes as shown in answer.