# RESX file editor for ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resx, multilingual

I am trying to build an multilanguage application in asp.net MVC with the support to update the resource file online. I found lot of resources for asp.net web forms but could not find any example for MVC. Could any one tell me how can I do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192465/how-to-localize-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Is this really possible? Since MVC is WAP, aren't resources necessarily satellite assemblies and not .resx files?

Answer (score 4):

I use resource files with access modifier set to "public", so resources can be accessed from everewhere (controllers, views) by static properties:

```
<%= GlobalTexts.HelloWorld %>
```

For editing resx file I use [Zeta resource editor](http://www.zeta-sw.com/zre/).

Comment: This piece of software looks pretty cool and it's free! Thanks for the link.