# DNS name gets changed randomly in metatags

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dns, application-pool

I have hosted an MVC web application in IIS7.5. The application is multilingual. For example:

www.myapp.com

www.myapp.ca

www.myapp.mx

www.myapp.co.in

fr.myapp.com

To generate metadata (URL in my case), I am using the below code.

```
 var url = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString();
```

The problem is:

lets say if I am browsing, www.myapp.mx, then while viewing view source, the meta tag URL says www.myapp.fr. The metatag is generated by using the same code shown above. Most of the time, it returns correct DNS name, but randomly it changes.

```
 public static string MetaData(this HtmlHelper helper, string type,        params object[] models)
    {
        var metaTags = new MetaDataBlock();
        metaTags.ogSiteName = helper.EncodedResource("MetaSiteName");
        metaTags.ogUrl = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString();
        metaTags.fbAppId = helper.EncodedResource("MetaFacebookAppID");
      // function to create meta data using String Buider
    }
```

In the above function, **ogUrl** changes, and points to random app endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You could check:
[MVC noob - changing part of URL in a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603444/mvc-noob-changing-part-of-url-in-a-link)
and
http://www.frankysnotes.com/2013/11/localization-from-url-with-aspnet-mvc-4.html

Good Luck.

Comment: I don't want to change it... It is bug some where (code, IIS, apppool, network), and because of it... even if someone wants to load hongkong site (www.app.hk), but the resources are getting loaded of canada (www.app.ca). Though the url remains the same.. but contents with in the page points to some other website... and keeps loading the same wrong content for a small duration of time, and then comes back to normal.