# MVC string constants where to store them

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I previously asked a question on here about whether there was an MVC option to store string constants in a resources file like in webforms.

Well the answer was that you just store them in the resources file just like in webforms.

Well where is the resources file? Do I need to add it?

I just added the App_LocalResources folder but I don't think that's it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970935/how-does-the-app-localresources-work-with-mvc) quite a while back. The answer is basically that the App_LocalResources doesn't work the same in MVC. Check out the [ASP.NET MVC2 Localization Complete Guide.](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html)

Comment: I think the question wasn't about localization, but regular string constants (that can be not necessarily localizable). For example if I have TempData["MyConst"] - where do I store that "MyConst" value?
For example so it will be come like this: TempData[Config.MyConst] instead of physical magic string inside code.