# how to localize an asp.net mvc webproject? languages support

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, localized

I would like to support many languages in an MVC project. I did it already using WebForms.
I used `LocalizedPage` class inherited from `Page`. In MVC I am inheriting `LocalizedPage` from a `System.Web.MVC.ViewPage`,

```
public class LocalizedPage : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage
```

and then my model uses it like this:

```
public class OverviewModel : Services.LocalizedPage
```

My problem is that it nothing happens at all. I am not landing in debug breakpoint in localizedPage.cs at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Please help me,
take care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192465/how-to-localize-asp-net-mvc-application) post.