# asp.net MVC 3 1 website in two language

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to localize ASP .Net MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192465/how-to-localize-asp-net-mvc-application)

Hello,
ich have a small mvc 3 project in which the user should be able to switch between two language (german and french) and i have absolutly no idea how to get it working.
can anyone explain it very simple and for someone who has only litty or 0 experience with asp mvc
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I may suggest you starting with the [complete guide](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html) and once you encounter some specific problems don't hesitate to show your progress (in terms of source code of course) and any specific problems you might have encountered on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). I am sure you will get good answers.

Answer (score 1):

I've a complete blog post on my blog on building multilingual website, it might help you https://dominicstpierre.com/aspnet-mvc-multilingual-websites.html.

The concept of changing language is not very hard by just adding the language in the route / url. As @Darin Dimitrov said, check it out and come back with more specific questions / source code.