# ASP.NET MVC SEO Friendly URL's

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo, url-routing

I have an ASP.NET MVC application, and the visitors can select from two languages to view the site. My question is: should the url's themselves also be language dependent, like:

/en/approach -> refers to the English page

/nl/aanpak -> refers to the Dutch page

or should I just use /en/approach for both english and dutch pages?

Thanks,
L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Phil said... It helps you, the search engine and helps your users understanding that it's separated content.

And!:

> Keep the content for each language on separate URLs. Don’t use cookies to show translated versions of the page. Consider cross-linking each language version of a page. That way, a French user who lands on the German version of your page can get to the right language version with a single click.
>
> Avoid automatic redirection based on the user’s perceived language. These redirections could prevent users (and search engines) from viewing all the versions of your site.
>
> - [Google, Multi-regional and multilingual sites](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192)

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to split them out.  It would allow search engines to index more pages and also makes the urls hackable.  Also, if you are planning to use output caching, you would easily be able to cache both localization.

Here is a good post about how to accomplish localization with MVC.
[How to localize ASP.NET MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192465/how-to-localize-asp-net-mvc-application)