# How should I go about handling localization using MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an application which I need to have work in more than one language. Can someone give me some pointers as to where I should start looking. For example can I decorate the fields in my models with different headings that could be used depending on the language in use?

My application also uses messages like this:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("username", "You must specify a username.");
```

How can I code these messages for different languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize a `ModelMetadataProvider` and a `ModelValidatorProvider` just as I've done in [Griffin.MvcContrib](https://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.mvccontrib).

With my versions, this is all you need to get localization of models and validations working:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    var stringProvider = new ResourceStringProvider(Resources.LocalizedStrings.ResourceManager);
    ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new LocalizedModelMetadataProvider(stringProvider);
    ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();
    ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new LocalizedModelValidatorProvider(stringProvider));
}
```

More info: http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/easy-model-and-validation-localization-in-asp-net-mvc3/

(nuget packages will be available as soon as I've got the administration area working with embedded views)

Answer (score 2):

here are some good reads

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/10/globalizing-mvc-validation.aspx

https://stackoverflow.com/q/2455409/413670