# The best way to implement XML localization in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization

We're developing a Asp.net MVC 3 application. One of the customer requirements that localization should be implemented using XML files. The customer is going to update them from time to time.

The structure should be as following:

```
<lang>
    <item key="moduleName">Admin</item>
    <item key="yes">Yes</item>
    <item key="no">No</item>
</lang>
```

What is the best way to implement that?
Could you point me to any good solution?

Comment: Similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192465/how-to-localize-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Nope. I've updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the resx format used by ASP.net is XML also, I would consider using it and not creating your own

```
  <data name="Anterior" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Previous</value>
  </data>
  <data name="Autos" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Cars</value>
  </data>
  <data name="AutosIncluidos" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Cars Included</value>
  </data>
```

Advantages:

- Already invented
- Works without any work in asp.net
- Several tools available the generate the format (like the lovely [Zeta Resource Editor](http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com/index.html))