# mvc .net multilingual application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create multilingual application in mvc.net. I want to add flags of the top of the screen so that user can change the language. 
Pleae guide me to do this.

Thanks 
Munish

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple languages in an ASP.NET MVC application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034/multiple-languages-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: Is your question how to create a multilingual application or how to add flags at the top of the screen?  Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034/multiple-languages-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 2):

Define this route:

```
routing.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, lang = "en" }
);
```

All your flags at the top should be done like:

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action(this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"], this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"], new { lang = "de" }) %>">
    <img scr="..." />
</a>
```

so they will always point to the current page in a different language. This is useful if your language variations are 1:1. But if your language pages are different, you should always point to home page in a particular language.

Regarding translations you can either use resources or you can store them in the DB. I used both in my past although lately I save static interface string in resource files. Not just one, because it become way too overwhelming, but rather one resource file per file if it needs it. This way I do get some repeated definitions (like OK, Cancel etc), but its much easier to maintain it this way. Because if you have only one resource file it become very unpredictable where do things change.

So all my `*.cs` files that need strings (ie. exception messages) have their `*.resx` companion. The same goes with my views. Views almost all have their own acompanying `*.resx` that defines all static content.

If you have more than one language, you'd have to provide `*.lang.resx` for every language you need.