# What's the efficient technique to implement multilingual in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, multilingual

What's the efficient technique to implement multilingual in ASP.net MVC?

Comment: This question is too broad... you're asking how to do i18n with ASP/C#, and there are quite a number of ways to do this, each of which may or may not be suited for what you want. You've also provided little to no other detail on how, specifically, you want this to work or what type of application you're building this for, so we can't tailor your answer to your specific needs, which only adds to my original point that this question **is too broad.** Did you try googling "ASP MVC Internationalization" or similar keywords to find what you're looking for?

Comment: I know there are a number of ways to implement multilingual but I want to hear from expert which one is the best.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple languages in an ASP.NET MVC application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034/multiple-languages-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you searched before you ask you question ?
there are many resources out there, have a look at the following links :

[Multiple languages in an ASP.NET MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034/multiple-languages-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

[Creating ASP.NET MVC Multilingual Web Application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASP_NET_MVC_Multilingual.aspx)

[Multilingual ASP.NET MVC website](http://dominicstpierre.net/archive/2010/05/26/multilingual-asp.net-mvc-website.aspx)

hope this help.

Comment: Thank you sir. these tutorials are great.

Comment: *StackOverflow: Replacing Google for lazy developers since 2008.*

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Resource file. Extension .resx

Example have English.resx for english and Spanish.resx for spanish and have a way to store the local of the user and when the app loads you load the appropriate resx file.

In those files you coule use the , where the key would be the same in all the files and value would be sentence/word in that language for that key.

The keys would be used in your app in place of typing text straight into a text available tag.

Answer (score 1):

Scott Hanselman wrote a good article covering this subject... Check it out here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx